# IIS SMTP settings and Host setting in web.config in ASP.Net

Tags: smtp

In IIS7, there is SMTP settings where you can specify the SMTP server for ASP.Net application to use. 
In Web.Config, you can also settup the host and port the SMTP server.

My question is: What's the difference between the two?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference.  IIS7 is reading & writing the values to your web.config.